# Reboot VMware View Connection Server

Tags: vmware-view

I hear that the VMView connection server will disconnect users when it is gracefully shut down. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed true, up to and including View 5. You can reboot the vCenter server gracefully and connections that are in use will remain, but no new connections can be made until the server is back up.

Reboot the Connection Server however, and it breaks everyone's connections until it's back up. If they have a dedicated desktop, this isn't usually a problem, just an inconvenience. But if you have any floating pools, this can wreak a bit of havoc if any desktops are in use and the reboot is not properly scheduled...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't completely true.
It actually depends on your settings.
In View Admin / Config / Server / Connection Server / Edit
You can choose to enable or disable the HTTPS Secure Tunnel or PCoIP Secure Gateway.

By disabling it, A direct connection is being initiated by the Connection Server between the View Client (Full/Thin/Zero) and View Agent (Desktop)
So if the Connection Server falls, the connection remains.

However if you do not tick this checkbox, the secure tunnel is enable, resulting in a better secure internal traffic (encrypted and tunnelled) but also less reliable as a reboot / crash of the connection server or network connection to it will disconnect existing sessions (PCoIP / TS)

To make it clear :
If you disable the tunnel, the connection looks like : Client <==> Agent
If you enable it : Client <=> Connection Server <=> Agent

Note : You can not disable secure tunnel for external connections because an external client with not be able to contact a agent (view desktop) using a private class IP address (192.168.0.* or 172.16.**, or 10.***)