# High Availabiltiy Mechanisms For VMWare View Connection Server

Tags: vmware-view

According to the question [Reboot VMware View Connection Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/307688/reboot-vmware-view-connection-server)
a reboot of the VCS disconnects all virtual desktops.

Are there any builtin mechanisms to provide high availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install secondary servers in replica mode to provide high-availability.

See [this](http://planetvm.net/blog/?p=73) blog for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Did you forget the link to the blog?

Comment: @ckliborn press the "this" :-)